# How to create the array for Facebook og:image?

Tags: html, facebook

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/) you can find a documentation how to set up the og-tags.
It is possible to give an array to the og:image-tag.

> Image > Array of images > Image[]

I tried a lot and did research but i can't find it out ...

.. how can i parse this Image[]-Array in the content attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, by specifying multiple qualifying og:image tags, you will get an array.

To code this is done by

> **Arrays**
>
> If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of the
>   same  tag on your page. The first tag (from top to bottom) is
>   given preference during conflicts.
>
> Put structured properties after you declare their root tag. Whenever
>   another root element is parsed, that structured property is considered
>   to be done and another one is started.
>
> For example:

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock.jpg" />`

`<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />`

`<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />`

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />`

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock3.jpg" />`

`<meta property="og:image:height" content="1000" />`

`<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />`

Please also read up on og meta tags at http://ogp.me.

Comment: Is this still possible with the latest FB api? Because couldn't find Thumbnail chooser in share dialog now.

Answer (score -3):

no, facebook automatically uses all images on the website that meet the following requirements: "Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall."

What you specify in the og:image is the default (the first) image displayed in share dialogs (and the image for the like story feed)

Comment: If i parse an image which is not on the site with the og:image, only this image is displayed. Even there are other images on this page.